# 1==(int)0.5*2 => false, 1==((int)0.5*2) => true, why?

Tags: groovy

See title. `1==(int)0.5*2` evaluates to false, but `1==((int)0.5*2)` evaluates to true. However `(1==(int)0.5)*2` gives an error so the first expression is not parsed as this. Somehow the extra parentheses in `1==((int)0.5*2)` are changing the precedence of the cast and the multiply.

What exactly causes this? And is this supposed to happen or is it a parsing bug?

Answer (score 1):

This is how the expression should look like:

```
1 == 0.5*2 as int //--> true
1 == (int)(0.5*2) //--> true
```

this one:

```
1==(int)0.5*2
```

gives `false`, as `(int)0.5 == 0`

and this one: `(1==(int)0.5)*2` doesn't make sense at all, as you try to multiply `false` (see the previous example) by 2, which is NOT allowed

Comment: I understand how the expressions get evaluated, my question is why the extra set of parentheses in `1==((int)0.5*2)` causes a difference in the evaluation.